# Ubuntu 18.04 starts without network

Tags: boot, networking

Ubuntu 18.04 boots without network. When I reboot the OS the network is okay. How can I make the network start on first boot? Where should I start looking? Is there a boot log I can look at? Where do I find that and what do I look for. I'm totally new to Linux, so I need all the advice I can get. The system I'm running is an old Intel motherboard with an i7 860 and Intel network on it. I find it curious that the network starts on reboot, but not on initial boot.

Comment: Wired or wireless?

Comment: Wired network 1000Mb/s

Comment: @KetilM Can you please edit the question to contain the detail?

Comment: There is not much more to add. It is what I see.